# How to construct new DataFrame based on data from for loops?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set (datacomplete2), where I have data for each country for two different years. I want to calculate the difference between these years for each country (for values life, health, and lifegdp) and create a new data frame with the results.

The code:

```py
for i in datacomplete2['Country'].unique():
    life.append(datacomplete2.loc[(datacomplete2['Country']==i)&(datacomplete2['Year']==2016), 'life'] - datacomplete2.loc[(datacomplete2['Country']==i)&(datacomplete2['Year']==2000), 'life'])
    health.append(datacomplete2.loc[(datacomplete2['Country']==i)&(datacomplete2['Year']==2016), 'health'] - datacomplete2.loc[(datacomplete2['Country']==i)&(datacomplete2['Year']==2000), 'health'])
    lifegdp.append(datacomplete2.loc[(datacomplete2['Country']==i)&(datacomplete2['Year']==2016), 'lifegdp'] - datacomplete2.loc[(datacomplete2['Country']==i)&(datacomplete2['Year']==2000), 'lifegdp'])

newData = pd.DataFrame([life, health, lifegdp, datacomplete2['Country'].unique()], columns = ['life', 'health', 'lifegdp', 'country'])

newData
```

I think the for loop for calculating is correct, and the problem is in creating the new DataFrame. When I try to run the code, I get an error message: 4 columns passed, passed data had 210 columns.

I have 210 countries so I assume it somehow throws these values to the columns?

Here is also a link to a sneak peek of the data I'm using: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjWnm.png

The data as text would look like:

```
    Country Code    Year    life    health  lifegdp

0   Algeria DZA 2000    70.292000   3.489033    20.146558

1   Algeria DZA 2016    76.078000   6.603844    11.520259

2   Angola  AGO 2000    47.113000   1.908599    24.684593

3   Angola  AGO 2016    61.547000   2.713149    22.684710

4   Antigua and Barbuda ATG 2000    73.541000   4.480701    16.412834

... ... ... ... ... ... ...

415 Vietnam VNM 2016    76.253000   5.659194    13.474181

416 World   OWID_WRL    2000    67.684998   8.617628    7.854249

417 World   OWID_WRL    2016    72.035337   9.978453    7.219088

418 Zambia  ZMB 2000    44.702000   7.152371    6.249955

419 Zambia  ZMB 2016    61.874000   4.477207    13.819775
```

Quick help required !!!

I started coding like two weeks ago so I'm very novice with this stuff.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `unique().tolist()`                                                                         
  `newData = pd.DataFrame([life, health, lifegdp, datacomplete2['Country'].unique().tolist()], columns = ['life', 'health', 'lifegdp', 'country'])
`

Comment: can you include the data in the post please - if you can put a sample of the data as text that would be better than an image.

Comment: Anurag Reddy, your solution gave me the same error, baxx I'll try to add asap in a readable format.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead

```py
country_list = df.Country.unique().tolist()
df.drop(columns = ['Code'])

df_2016 = df.loc[(df['Country'].isin(country_list))&(df['Year']==2016)].reset_index()
df_2000 = df.loc[(df['Country'].isin(country_list))&(df['Year']==2000)].reset_index()
df_2016.drop(columns=['Year'])
df_2000.drop(columns=['Year'])
df_2016.set_index('Country').subtract(df_2000.set_index('Country'), fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the parantheses

Comment: This one gave me `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: That's weird, I tried this with a dummy example and it worked fine. You will get that error if some of your value columns are probably in string format. So, you might have to use `df['col'] = pd.to_numeric([df['col'], errors=coerce).fillna(0).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

[Anurag Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9530965/anurag-reddy)'s answer is a good concise solution if you know the dates in advance. To present an alternative and slightly more general answer - this problem is a good example use case for [pandas.DataFrame.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html).

Note you don't actually need to sort the data in your example data but I've included a `sort_values()` line below to account for unsorted DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the raw datafile in
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv")

# Sort the data if required
df.sort_values(by=["Country"], inplace=True)

# Remove columns where you don't need the difference
new_df = df.drop(["Code", "Year"], axis=1)

# Group the data by country, take the difference between the rows, remove NaN rows, and reset the index to sequential integers
new_df = new_df.groupby(["Country"], as_index=False).diff().dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

# Add back the country names and codes as columns in the new DataFrame
new_df.insert(loc=0, column="Country", value=df["Country"].unique())
new_df.insert(loc=1, column="Code", value=df["Code"].unique())
```

Comment: Thank you  for the clear format, I'm getting the error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'groupby'`, and after removing the groupdby function, I get: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`.

Comment: You're trying to perform `groupby` on a DataFrame you've already grouped. When you run `df.groupby()` that returns a DataFrameGroupBy object, not a DataFrame object. I can't see your full code but from your original question, is `datacomplete2` a DataFrame or a DataFrameGroupBy object? Check this using `print(type(datacomplete2))`. You should see `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.